# VBA Remove parentheses from columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format a spreadsheet by searching through three columns and removing any parentheses. Currently, I have:

```
Range("B:D").Select
Selection.Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

When I run the code, I get:

Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: There must be another issue because this runs fine for me.

Comment: `Range("B:D")` may refer to `Sheet1` in `Workbook1` or `Sheet2` in `Workbook2`, etc. Which one is proper?
What i'm trying to say is you have to use code in context!

Comment: Maciej, this should run in all cases since columns B-D will exist on every sheet.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to say ;)

Comment: Ah.  Well, it's not the problem, but removing selects is always desirable.  `Range("B:D").Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows`

Comment: Perhaps your Activesheet is not a Worksheet (`?ActiveSheet.Type=xlWorksheet`)? Launch Object Browser and search for `XlSheetType`.

Comment: Unless you are going to do this for a high number of sheets, just use the built in find and replace function in excel. Select columns B,C & D. Find `(` replace with blank. Find `)` replace with blank.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you qualify with Sheet Name, not using Select?

```
Sheet1.Range("B:D").Replace What:="(", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Sheet1.Range("B:D").Replace What:=")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```